# Unable to receive chatHistory Object from open fire chat application using angular 4 and Spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, openfire

I am creating a chat application using Open Fire as XMPP server. I am able to log in into a server which is confirmed through logged in into open fire administration console.
Now I have to start communication between the two users.
When I sent the message to the user, it not get received by another from another browser. Another user is getting the CHatHistory object as blank.

this is my code,

```
 getUserSpecificChat(){
        this.userSpecificChatHistory = ChatHistoryService.getUserChatObjectFromChatHistory(this.loggedInUser.toLowerCase());

      }
```

this is the code for chatHistoryService.getUserChatObjectFromChatHistory method,

```
this.getUserChatObjectFromChatHistory = function(userName){
                    console.log("User Chat",this.userChat);
                    var chatData;
                    if(!this.userChat)
                        return [{}];
                    for(var i=0;i<this.userChat.length;i++){
                        if(this.userChat[i].userName.toLowerCase() === userName.toLowerCase()){
                            chatData = this.userChat[i].chat;
                            console.log("chat data will be return",chatData);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return chatData;
                };
```

Please any one help me to solve this issue?